# Populate Table Content with Data From Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been searching on how to achieve this. I got a lot of info from this site, but all couldn't help.

I'm trying to populate a table with the data I got from PHP File Using Ajax
I've been able to get the data, at least into the console. But when i try sending it to the the table, nothing is shown. No errors shown, Just blank.

```
console.log(newarr)
```

brings
 [gives this answer (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zxfS.png)

But when I do this `$("#report").html(newarr);`, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

ajax

```
$.post('./process/assetReport.php', data, function(data) {
  genData = JSON.parse(data);
  var newarr;

  for (var key in genData) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      newarr = genData[key];
      //console.log(newarr);
      $("#report").html(newarr);

    }
  }

});
```

php

```
foreach($all as $item) {
  $assetid = $item['assetid'];
  $staffid = $item['staffid'];
  $row2 = $user->showone('assets', 'assetid', $assetid);
  $row3 = $user->showone('staff', 'staffid', $staffid);
  $useData[] = array(
    'asset' => $row2['name'],
    'staff' => $row3['name'],
    'cost' => $item['cost']
  );
}
echo json_encode($useData);
```

The table I need to populate

```
<table class="table" id="reportTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset Name</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="report">

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="printReport"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I hope my question is explanatory enough
Thank you

Comment: some html context around `#report` would be helpful, is it a table, a div, or what?  In short `$("#report").html()` is just replacing the contents of `#report` everytime that line is run, not appending//

Comment: @Steve I've added them. It's a table. Yes, replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a stub of a `JSON` array, and shown how to loop through it appending rows to your table as you go.  I excluded your key check, as I wasn't sure the relevance.  A variation of this code should reside in the callback to your `$.post()`

```js
data = [{
  asset: "steve",
  staff: "steve",
  cost: '$999,999.99'
}, {
  asset: 'bob',
  staff:"bob",
  cost: '$0.99'
}];
var $row = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"); //the row template
var $tr;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  $tr = $row.clone(); //create a blank row
  $tr.find("td:nth-child(1)").text(item.asset); //fill the row
  $tr.find("td:nth-child(2)").text(item.staff);
  $tr.find("td:nth-child(3)").text(item.cost);
  $("#report").append($tr); //append the row
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset Name</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='report'>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in   {"asset":"Fan","staff":"asfa","cost":"50"}}
    at s (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (index.php?report:313)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: I have modified the answer, but am not sure what you are saying in your comment.  I do notice that your PHP references two different rows when building your json.  Do you know if your JSON is correct when being returned?

Comment: Yes, the JSON being returned is correct. I checked it

Comment: I'm getting this error.    `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in   {":asset":"2","0":
    {"asset":"Fan","staff":"ghkfhg","cost":"23"},"1":
    {"asset":"Fan","staff":"asfa","cost":"50"}}
    at s (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (index.php?report:311)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: Wow. Its working now. I used the `genData = JSON.parse(data);` so instead of `data` I used `genData`. Thanks. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to user genData[0] instead of genData as your are using $useData[] inside php or user $useData instead of $useData[]

So the code should be look like followings:

```
$.post( './process/assetReport.php', data, function (data) {
     genData = JSON.parse(data);

     var newarr;

     for(var key in genData[0]) {
         if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
              newarr = genData[key];

              //console.log(newarr);
               $("#report").html(newarr);

         }
     }

});
```

And the php:

```
foreach ($all as $item) {
    $assetid = $item['assetid'];
    $staffid = $item['staffid'];
    $row2 = $user->showone('assets', 'assetid', $assetid);
    $row3 = $user->showone('staff', 'staffid', $staffid);
    $useData[] = array(
        'asset' => $row2['name'],
        'staff' => $row3['name'],
        'cost' => $item['cost']
    );
}
echo json_encode($useData);
```